# Geany: wheres the status bar?

Tags: software-rec, geany

Im using geany to write code, used it for ages, I like the part where there is a status bar, or tab, compiler, messages, and terminal tab. those have dissapeared, and I cant figure out how to get them back. I even tried purging geany, and reinstalling, but they have not returned. I am on a raspberry pi running ubuntu Mate 20.04. I also tried building from source code, but I still don't have these features. I must have clicked something, but I can't figure out what. I looked all over the preferences, and tried reloading the config files. Can someone tell me how to get these features back? [image: where the status bar?]

Comment: Did you look under the view. I see show messages & show toolbar.

Comment: aw man, there it is. it was checked. I unchecked it, then checked it again and the bar appeared. lol thanks.